# Linear Regression Code

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am taking *Andrew Ng class* on *Machine Learning* and implementing linear regression algorithm.

What is wrong with my code?

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
m = length(y); 
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);
h = (X*theta)
for iter = 1:num_iters
    theta(1,1) = theta(1,1)-(alpha/m)*sum((h-y).*X(:,1));
    theta(2,1) = theta(2,1)-(alpha/m)*sum((h-y).*X(:,2));  
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
end
end
```

Cost Function is given as:

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
m = length(y); 
h = (X*theta)
J = (1/(2*m))*sum((h-y).^2)
end
```

The value of `J_history` keeps increasing. It is giving very abnormal (large value) i.e. about 1000 times more than it should.

[image]

Comment: It's much easier to answer a question like this if you explain how you know something is wrong. This means either posting the full error message (preferably with example input) or posting the output and explaining why it differs from what you expected. You can edit your post to add these things.

Comment: the value of J_history keeps increasing It is giving very abnormal (large value) i.e. about 1000 times more than it should. .

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Otherwise its very hard to debug a numerical algorithm

Comment: Shouldn't you update `h` after `theta`?

Comment: You're updating `h` in the `computeCost` function but not taking it as an output argument and hence your code keeps using the previous value of `h`

Comment: To clarify above comment, you should put `h = (X*theta)` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks all 
it's working 
You are all amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `h` and `theta` in the for loop as below

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
m = length(y); 
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters
    h = ((X*theta)-y)'*X;
    theta = theta - alpha*(1/m)*h';
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
end
end
```